# Unable to load JSON file via jQuery on localhost

Tags: jquery, json

I have

```
var module = (function(){
     return{
        loadData: function(){
           $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/App/data/test.json', function(data){
             console.log(data);
           });
        }
     }
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
     module.loadData();
});
```

But this does not load the data. I get error 404.

```
Failed to load resource at
http://localhost:8080/
```

It gives data when URL http://localhost:8080/App/data/blog.json is put in browser address bar directly

Comment: What happens when you input the `http://localhost:8080/App/data/test.json` URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: It gives data at http://localhost:8080/App/data/test.json when put in browser directly

Comment: What is the url of the page where you load the JS ? does it starts with http://localhost:8080/ ?

Comment: Sounds like CORS issue. Are you trying to access the data via ajax on a different `domain:port` than where the AJAX request is being made to?

Comment: @show-me-the-code — `404` implies it isn't a CORS issue (`404` combined with the description of the problem implies there is a fault with the tests).

Answer (score 0):

You get the 404 because $.getJSON will alter the value of the URL into something like this:

`http://localhost:8080/App/data/test.json?_=1444401510054`

See that `_=1444401510054` appended to the end of the request URL, that's your culprit, depending on the server-side REST implementation it basically can't locate an appropriate controller method and it returns a 404...

I'd suggest sticking to $.ajax :)